# Can I show a gif animation in a Photos.app slideshow?

Tags: photos.app, animation

I'm creating a slideshow/movie in Photos, and some of my photos are actually animated gifs, but they appear as low quality stills in the slideshow.

Any way Photos can properly support these gifs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the stock Photos app simply does not support the *.gif file type. To view *.gifs on a Mac you have 3 options:

1. Locate the file in a Finder window, highlight it, and then press the
   spacebar
2. Locate the file in a Finder window, right-click, and choose to open
   in Safari
3. Install a 3rd party application with *.gif support (such as 'PhotoScape
   X' or 'Fragment', both free in the App Store. Unfortunately neither of these have the ability to create slide-shows)

I understand none of the above options help you with your slideshow project, and for that I apologize, but there is currently no way to make this happen.

With the addition of the Photos.app extensions (as of El Capitan) I was expecting someone to come out with an extension for *.gif support, but I have yet to find one or hear of one after searching tirelessly through the App Store and performing countless Google searches.

Comment: thanks, maybe when such extension pops up, someone will be kind enough to add a new answer to this question...